# Show Regression Line Equation in FusionCharts

Tags: fusioncharts

Is there a configuration setting anywhere in FusionCharts that would enable a regression line equation (in the form of "y = mx + b") to be displayed along with the scatter plot & graphical regression line (as is possible in Excel)?  I've looked hard for this - but just don't find it.  Thanks.

Comment: Typically SO is for programming questions rather than questions related to settings that can (more than likely) be found via the proper Google search.

Answer (score 0):

FusionCharts does support Regression line. Check a demo at [Link](http://www.fusioncharts.com/explore/regression-line/)

To display regression lines of all the datasets of a chart you need to declare **showRegressionLine='1'** in the  element. You can show the regression line for a particular  element declaring **showRegressionLine='1'** in that particular  element.